# URLS Django not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a user form and then post the input to the database model.However I keep getting this error message

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/hiresite/Recruiter
Using the URLconf defined in recruitment.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^hiresite ^$ [name='index']

^hiresite ^Recruiter$ [name='Recruiter']

^admin/

The current URL, hiresite/Recruiter, didn't match any of these.

I am a bit confused because I can see the url Recruiter above and yet  I get the error message.Your help would be much appreciated .

1.Here is my Urls.py for the app

```
from django .conf.urls import url

from. import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',  views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^Recruiter$',  views.Recruiter, name='Recruiter')

]
```

2.Here is my Urls.py for the Project

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hiresite',  include('hiresite.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

3.Here is the view for the Url Recruiter

```
def Recruiter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = register_job(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = request.POST.get('title', ' ')
            description = request.POST.get('description', ' ')
            salary = request.POST.get('salary', ' ')
            reference = request.POST.get('reference', ' ')


            user_obj = jobsearch(title=title, description=description, salary=salary, reference=reference)
            user_obj.save()

            return render(request, 'hiresite/Recruiter.html', {'user_obj ': user_obj, 'is_registered': True})
        else:
            form = register_job()
            return render(request, 'hiresite/Recruiter.html', {'form': form})
```

4.Here is the Html template file used in the views.py file for the Url Recruiter

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Learning Html the Hard way</title>
<meta  charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel='stylesheet' href=  " {% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = 'text/css'/>    
</head>
<body>



 <form action="{% url 'hiresite:Recruiter' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

convert this line :

```
url(r'^hiresite',  include('hiresite.urls')),
```

To this line :

```
url(r'^hiresite/',  include('hiresite.urls')),
```